# converting each element of array into time using date() in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in php like the one given below

```
$each_session_time=array("2700","3356","3278","5452");
```

the issue is i want to convert each element in this array into time 
i tried using

```
date("h:i:s",$each_session_array);
```

but it didn't work because date function doesn't work with arrays...
so can anyone help me in converting the each element into time....I shall be very thankful to you

```
 $each_session_time=array();
 for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($array_in_time_str) ; $i++) { 
$each_session_time[$i]=$array_out_time_str[$i]-$array_in_time_str[$i];
                                                  }
```

Comment: did you try array_map ??

Comment: @AhmadHajjar no i dint try that

Comment: the input array is array of timestamps right?

Comment: @AhmadHajjar and now i want to convert the hour sec and minutes to minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your request, then this is what you need : using `array_map` here is a [demo](https://eval.in/627608)

```
  <?php

  $each_session_time=array(2700,33522,2222278,1111452);

  $res = array_map(function($elem){
      return date ("H:i:s",$elem);
  },$each_session_time);

  print_r($res);
  ?>
```

Comment: You are welcome, if this solved your problem please accept the answer and give it a +1 :)

Comment: This will show time after `$elem` seconds passed since Unix Epoch start.

Comment: And in your example demo `2700` seconds is 12 hours, okaaaay.

Comment: @u_mulder that's true, he wanted to convert the given values into time format :)

Comment: I suppose OP wants for 2700 seconds to show 00:45:00 (which is 45 minutes)

Comment: @AhmadHajjar now i want to convert each result to minutes like 1:45:20 to 105 minutes

Comment: @u_mulder this actually related to the formatting :D h:i:s instead of H:i:s

Comment: @AhmadHajjar shoul i again use array_map in the body of prev function to convert h:i:s to minutes only

Comment: @iqra yes sure you have to do that :)

Comment: @AhmadHajjar thank u sir u saved me alot of time..thankx alot is there any algo that should convert H:i:s to minutues only

Comment: @iqra you are welcome, but notice that you have to change your datetime format from `h:i:s` to `H:i:s` to avoid what u_mulder has mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
$each_session_time=array("2700","3356","3278","5452");
foreach ($each_session_time as $key => $value) {
   $timeArray[] = date("h:i:s",$value);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($timeArray);
Output:
Array
 (
  [0] => 06:15:00
  [1] => 06:25:56
  [2] => 06:24:38
  [3] => 07:00:52
 )
```